# Prepare Live-Stick WITH extra data on 2nd partition

Tags: linux, live-usb, data

- I have a USB Stick of 64 GB.
- I have a debian ISO.
- I can make myself a bootable USB stick with `sudo cp debian.iso /dev/sdb`

**Problem 1:**

I cannot copy various files to the stick preventing them to be deleted with the next ISO-copy of a newer version of my Debian.

So I'd like to partitioning my stick in one partition of 3 GB for the live data and a second one for the space left.

**Problem 2:**

With copying the ISO like mentioned above the partitions and their data will be deleted.

What do I have to do to achieve my goal?

**Edit (2018-06-22)**

@Tomasz made a good suggestion to take a look into [MultiBootUSB](http://multibootusb.org/) - so I will.

May one cann suggest some steps on CLI? I'd like to dig into the mechanics for myself. It's a good opportunity to learn some things.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you [MultiBootUSB](http://multibootusb.org/), which not only will take care of writing the image and making the USB bootable, but will also do this on a partition you point it to. Moreover, you can prepare with it a USB with many OSs to boot (as the name MultiBootUSB suggests).

The steps to use it are simple and it comes with GUI. First partition your USB, then run the tool. You can test from within the app.

The downside is that it may not star in your standard repository, and so you have to download and install it yourself.